# Using multiple keywords in pyplot.axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Using `matplotlib` in Python, how could I pass two keywords to `pyplot.axis()`?  Something like:
`pyplot.axis('tight', 'off')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around the help and the source, I don't think you can do that.

From `help(pyplot.axis)`:

```
axis(*v, **kwargs)
    Convenience method to get or set axis properties.
```

*Convenience method*. This, to me, already suggests that we shouldn't have too high expectations regarding the method. The rest of the help also seems to suggest that only a single string argument can be passed.

So let's look at the source. For me, `pyplot.axis` is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py`. On line 1443 begins the definition of `axis`, and without further ado it simply passes the problem to the underlying axes object:

```
return gca().axis(*v, **kwargs)
```

So we need the `axis()` method of an `Axes` object usually. This class is defined in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py`, but it turns out that it doesn't have an `axis()` method defined. So, it's inherited from `_AxesBase` instead. This resides in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py`.

Now, `_AxesBase` finally implements `axis()`. The beginning:

```
def axis(self, *v, **kwargs):                                                                         
    """Set axis properties.                                                                           

    Valid signatures::                                                                                

      xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis()
      xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis(list_arg)
      xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis(string_arg)                                                       
      xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = axis(**kwargs)

    ...
```

Well, this docstring doesn't look good, again it suggests that only a single string argument can be provided. Looking at the implementation supports this impression. The string-based inputs are handled in a block beginning like this:

```
    if len(v) == 1 and is_string_like(v[0]):
        s = v[0].lower()
        if s == 'on':
            self.set_axis_on()
        elif s == 'off':
            self.set_axis_off()
        elif s in ('equal', 'tight', 'scaled', 'normal',
                   'auto', 'image', 'square'):

            ...
```

These strings don't appear anywhere in the method outside this `if` block, but the condition of the `if` clearly assumes scalar input, or in the worst case a single-element iterable. This means that you cannot pass multiple strings at the same time to `axis`.

Note that you *can* look at what each option does, and manually use them if you wish. Of course the result should be equivalent to you calling `pyplot.axis` multiple times, but the order of the commands will be well-defined (which might matter), and you can get rid of some overhead in the function calls.

Comment: I eventually used two lines of code:
`pyplot.axis('tight')`
`pyplot.axis('off')`
to achieve what I need.